# PHP page inserts a blank record as soon as user visits page. Why?

Tags: php, wordpress, insert-query

I have this basic php insert script working fine and it will insert the form perfectly once the user hits submit. However, for some reason it also submits a record when the user simply visits the page before they even hit submit. Right away at the top it echoes "Entry Successful" before the user even does anything. There will be a blank record in the database. Why is this happening?

As a bonus question...can I prevent sql injection buy simply adding some mysql_escape code to various parts of this? It is a WordPress page, so is that even necessary?

```
<?php
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();

$hostname = "******";
$username = "******";
$dbname = "******";
$password = "*****";

//Connecting to your database
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to 
connect to database! Please try again later.");
mysql_select_db($dbname);

// Get values from form 
$genre = $_POST['genre'];
$movie_name = $_POST['movie_name'];
$movie_text = $_POST['movie_text'];


$query = "INSERT INTO movies (ID, genre, movie_name, movie_text)  VALUES
('$user_ID','$genre','$story_name','$story_text')";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result)
{
echo("
Entry Succesful");
}
else
{
echo("
failed to start");
}

?>

Get started!
<br><br>
<form name="movie" action="" method="post">

What type of movie? <select name="genre">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<option value="Comedy">Comedy</option>
<option value="Drama">Drama</option>

</select>

Name of Movie: <input type="text" size="55" name="movie_name">

<textarea rows="30" cols="80" name="movie_text" rows="4"></textarea>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Add movie" />
</form>
```

Comment: um, guess what... the script runs. Exactly because the user opens the page.

Comment: stay away from `mysql_` functions, you have no reason why you should use that, use `PDO` or `mysqli_` and use parameterized queries

Comment: You issue the database query without probing if there is actual input. The script does not magically know that it should wait for the second page request.

Comment: Considering you have absolutely zero code to decide whether or not to perform the insert, is it any surprise it happens on each request? Also, don't use direct database calls in Wordpress. It gives you the [`$wpdb`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) object to work with.

Comment: Thanks all. Mario, what is the method for determining if there is user input?

Comment: Never mind...didn't see the answer below from Fred which I will accept as soon as it lets me in a few minutes. Thanks again all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"However, for some reason it also submits a record when the user simply visits the page before they even hit submit."*

Wrap your code inside an (if) [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) conditional statement, using your (named) submit button as a reference:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
    ...

else
{
echo("
failed to start");
}

    } // end brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))
?>

Get started!
<br><br>
<form name="movie" action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Add movie" />

...

</form>
```

As far as SQL injection goes, visit:

- [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

on Stack.

Answer (score 0):

You need  to check whether user is hitting submit button or not, else php script will execute every time you run a page or request a page. you can use `isset` to check that. try below code

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
    $hostname = "******";
    $username = "******";
    $dbname = "******";
    $password = "*****";
    //Connecting to your database
    mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to 
    connect to database! Please try again later.");
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

    // Get values from form 
    $genre = $_POST['genre'];
    $movie_name = $_POST['movie_name'];
    $movie_text = $_POST['movie_text'];


    $query = "INSERT INTO movies (ID, genre, movie_name, movie_text)  VALUES
    ('$user_ID','$genre','$story_name','$story_text')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result)
    {
    echo("
    Entry Succesful");
    }

}
```

else
        {
        echo("
        failed to start");
        }
    ?>

```
Get started!
<br><br>
<form name="movie" action="" method="post">

What type of movie? <select name="genre">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<option value="Comedy">Comedy</option>
<option value="Drama">Drama</option>

</select>

Name of Movie: <input type="text" size="55" name="movie_name">

<textarea rows="30" cols="80" name="movie_text" rows="4"></textarea>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Add movie" />
</form>
```

hope this help :)